# How do i dictate the size of the 'animate pulse' feature using css?

Tags: css

```
.element {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}
```

This animates the element to almost double the size of the original. how do i make the pulse smaller?

Comment: This isnt a "why isn't this code working?" question, the code works. As it says in the question, how do i control the size that it animates to when pulsing?

Comment: obviously this is no code of yours because you woud know where your answer stands. any tutorial on animation will give the hint

Comment: You need to show the **whole** code that makes this work...for instance, where is the keyframes code? That's why we ask for a demo.

Comment: sorry chaps, didn't realise there was so much to animating the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need more to get this working than you think.

```
.element {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}
```

The 'pulse' is the name of your animation, not a css command. So 'pulse' in this case needs to have parameters set. This is done by stipulating the keyframes. For example if you are 'pulsing' text...

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0%{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

Notice that the '0%' and '100%' are the same value? this is so it loops around so it will be smooth if you make it infinite.

Comment: thank you! that's what I was after. I thought 'pulse' was a css command and copied it from another site. I didn't realise that there was more I needed to add to this.